# How do I find a recurrence relation for a recursive method?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, recurrence

So I'm trying to find a recurrence relation for this java method:

```
public static Pair min/max(int start, int end, int[] a) {
        int mid;
        Pair pair = new Pair(a[start], a[end]);
        Pair p1;
        Pair p2;

        if (start == end) { //if n = 1
            return pair;
        }

        else if (end == start + 1) { //if n = 2
            if (a[start] > a[end]) {
                pair.upper = a[end];
                pair.lower = a[start];
            } else {
                pair.upper = a[start];
                pair.lower = a[end];
            }
            return pair;
        }

        mid = (end + start) / 2; //if n > 2
        p1 = min/max(end, mid, a);
        p2 = min/max(mid + 1, ub, a);

        if (p1.lower < p2.lower)
            pair.upper = p1.lower;
        else
            pair.lower = p2.lower;

        if (p1.upper > p2.upper)
            pair.upper = p1.upper;
        else
            pair.upper = p2.upper;

        return pair; //the min and max pair
    }
```

This is supposed to find the max and min of an array by always using ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ comparisons. It also uses this class:

```
class Pair {
   int lower;
   int upper;
   Pair ( int a, int o ) { lower = a; upper = o; }
}
```

So what would be the recurrence relation for this method? I know that it starts out as:

```
C(n) = 0 if n=1
       1 if n=2
```

And now I'm trying to figure out what the equation would be when n > 2. First off does the above method always run in ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ comparisons. I'm just wondering because of the line `mid = (lb + ub) / 2` which makes me think that I'm still splitting the array into ⌈n/2⌉ and ⌊n/2⌋ parts which would not get me ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ comparisons each time. I know that there is a better way to do this same thing but the code I'm writing has to use recursion.

UPDATE: After adding counter statements I find that the above code does not use ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ comparisons for every array. I think the problem is with the variable mid. With mid I'm supposed to split the array however I don't think I'm splitting it correctly to have the proper number of comparisons.

Comment: Josh, as far as I know, 3*n/2-2 is the best algorithm for solving min/max in an array; it is a fairly easy one.  It does not benefit from recursion (although could be written recursively).  i am curious why you chose to attack this problem with recursion.  Was it a requirement?

Comment: Yes. I'm not even sure if my recursive algorithm runs in ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ but I assume it does since this one is an improvement over my last algorithm which recursively split the array into ⌈n/2⌉ and ⌊n/2⌋ parts. This one basically does a different type of split that will always have ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ comparisons. Now I'm just trying to find out what the recurrence relation would be for this algorithm.

Comment: First off, does the above method always run in ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ comparisons and if it does then how can I write a recurrence relation for it. I'm still not too sure about that method because of the line 'mid = (lb + ub) / 2' which makes me think I'm still splitting the array in half which would not get me ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ comparisons every time.

Comment: Josh, to achieve the optimum 3*n/2-2, the following two conditions must be true:  1)  You start by sorting two elements of the array, and assign min and max based on the sort.  This takes one comparison operation.  2)  Every subsequent operation involves two new elements.  These elements are sorted (comparison 1).  The lowest is compared to the current min (comparison 2).  The highest is compared to the current max (comparison 3).  If you review your code, are you compliant with these two conditions?

Comment: Ok so I added a few counter statements and it appears to be giving me the wrong number of comparisons. For example, when n=6 I should be getting 7 comparisons but it's giving me 8 which is the same as my first method. I think the problem is how I'm splitting the array. I need to try and split it in such a way that I get ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Let `n = end - start + 1`.  I presume you mean a recurrence expressing the number of comparisons.

In the general case you are doing 4 comparisons for each level of recursion and splitting the list in half. So the recurrence is:

```
T(n) = 4 + T( floor(n/2) ) + T( ceiling(n/2) ) for n > 1
```

NB: You seem to have begun with `lb` and `ub` and switched only partially to `start` and `end`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to match with the ⌈3n/2 - 2⌉ number of comparisons. The number seems way too high.

Comment: It does and is. You're burning comparisons to detect base cases, when clever implementations use sentinels or - less clever - authors just ignore those comparisons. @JoshSusa

Comment: @JoshSusa Another point is that it would be trivially easy to add a static counter of comparisons and verify your math experimentally.